# Can I submit two forms at once?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

When a user clicks submit, I want to submit one form containing the textual info - name, email, etc. and one form to submit containing a picture.  The textual info. I want sent via an AJAX call and the picture I want submitted via and iframe according to this [link](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/).

I haven't seen this done typcially - if you look at some of the more popular sites, like twitter.com, facebook.com, etc. it seem they separate these tasks.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I submit two forms on single click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361370/how-can-i-submit-two-forms-on-single-click)

Comment: Are you using regular javascript or jquery?

Comment: Any particular library handling your ajax, or custom code?

Comment: custom code.  If I send the ajax call and then do a post, I think it should work.  The server should not have a problem responding to multiple requestes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just submit one form via ajax call and the other by regular post.  The textual info. is sent via an ajax call.  Because ajax does not support file uploads, this must be done via post or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

You can't by normal way. You can, with ajax

```
$.post({'url': 'ajax.php', 
         data: $("#form1").serialize(),
         success: function(){
             $("#form2").submit();
         }
});
```

Comment: @JonathanM: I'll add it to my answer